# Traversing DOM in a table

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML table that has a delete button in each row of its last column. By clicking on one of these buttons, I would like to be able to delete the whole row in which it is situated. The follow code deletes the button itself but I am unable to get it to delete the whole row:

```
var bns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (var i = 0; i < bns.length; i++) {
    bns[i].addEventListener("click", function()
  {
   this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this);    
  });
  }
```

My HTML looks like:

```
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Students</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@doe.us</td>
      <td><button>X</button></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@doe.us</td>
      <td><button>X</button></td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One more `parentNode` should do. The second is the row, but then you're deleting its child.

Comment: `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);` should work. Essentially `tbody.removeChild(tr)`.

Comment: `.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode)` instead of just `.removeChild(this)` as `this` is the button which isn't a child of `tbody`

Comment: Thanks Andreas and  h2ooooooo, that did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the `removeChild(this)` that's the problem. That's being called on the `<tr>` but it's telling it to delete `this` which is the button.

Try:

```
var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

Alternatively with a framework such as jQuery it would be:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

## Edit

The complete jQuery code is actually nice and short, too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: or even better IMO in jQuery for readability: `$(this).parents('tr').remove()`.

Comment: Or without any framework but an actual browser: `this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()`

Comment: I "borrowed" your improvement @h2ooooooo hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Thanks, guess I didn't understand the construction     this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);  So the first part describes the element to apply removeChild to and the parentheses at the end contain the actual element to be removed?

Comment: @DougMcLean I'd like for you to transfer $200 to my account by tomorrow, thank you. If I could patent a line of code I'd be so rich! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HTMLTableElement.deleteRow()`to delete a HTML table row. I have added an onclick event to each button and it will call deleteRow function which uses `rowIndex` & `deleteRow()`.It do not require jquery to perform the action

HTML

```
<table class="table" id="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Students</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@doe.us</td>
      <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">X</button></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john1@doe.us</td>
      <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">X</button></td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(i);
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/27vxvre4/)

Comment: Thanks but would prefer to use event listeners in JS as opposed to onclicks in HTML.